# how to fill contour colors and write axes names in RSM (R)

Tags: r, graphics

I have following data

```
ct<-structure(list(Conc = c(50L, 100L, 150L, 50L, 100L, 150L, 50L, 
100L, 150L, 100L, 100L, 100L), kGy = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 15L, 15L, 15L), CT.Y. = c(75L, 65L, 51L, 
87L, 93L, 89L, 81L, 86L, 78L, 92L, 93L, 92L)), .Names = c("Conc", 
"kGy", "CT.Y."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

And i am using following R code for response surface

```
library(rsm)
ct.rsm<-rsm(CT.Y.~SO(Conc, kGy), data=ct)
persp(ct.rsm, Conc ~ kGy, col=rainbow(50), theta=60,
    phi=0, r = 3, d=1, border = NULL, ltheta = -135, lphi = 0
    , shade = 0.75, zlab="CT",ylab="Concentration %", col.axis=37, font.lab=2,col.lab=33,
    contour=("colors"))
```

One question is that how can i fill the colors in contours?
and other question is about the axes labeling. For label of X and Z axes i can label it, but when i want to include the label of Y-axis, i receive following error.

```
Error in persp.default(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z, xlab = dat$labs[1], ylab = dat$labs[2],  : 
  formal argument "ylab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Hope that some one can help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.
[image: Response Surface Plot]

Comment: I tried loading the data but that structure is incomplete. Usually problems like that are due to the author of the package hard-coding a "ylab" so you need to hack that function. I admit it's a bit strange since you didn't even specify a ylab and the function is the default version of `persp`

Comment: Sorry for error in code. Please check the updated code in which i have included ylab. Response surface curve looks nice, but i also need the colors in the contours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I pieced together a working example of your data (without your rownames). The object returned from the rsm function is classes "rsm" "lm", so it gets handled by persp.lm. That function has a hard-coded ylab specification and no provision for relabeling. It can be fixed (with a puzzling reversal of x and ylabs). I changed the `line` function in `draw.cont.line` to polygon and it illustrates the need for further efforts to link up the endpoints as mentioned in my comment below:

```
    persp.lm <- 
function (x, form, at, bounds, zlim, zlab, xlabs, col = "white", xlab=xlab,
    contours = NULL, hook, atpos = 3, theta = -25, phi = 20, 
    r = 4, border = NULL, box = TRUE, ticktype = "detailed", ylab,
    ... ) 
{
    draw.cont.line = function(line) {
        if (cont.varycol) {
            cont.col = col
            if (length(col) > 1) 
                cont.col = col[cut(c(line$level, dat$zlim), length(col))][1]
        }
        polygon(trans3d(line$x, line$y, cont.z, transf), col = cont.col, 
            lwd = cont.lwd)
    }
    plot.data = contour.lm(x, form, at, bounds, zlim, xlabs, 
        atpos = atpos, plot.it = FALSE)
    transf = list()
    if (missing(zlab)) 
        zlab = ""
    facet.col = col
    cont = !is.null(contours)
    if (mode(contours) == "logical") 
        cont = contours
    cont.first = cont
    cont.z = cz = plot.data[[1]]$zlim[1]
    cont.col = 1
    cont.varycol = FALSE
    cont.lwd = 1
    if (is.character(contours)) {
        idx = charmatch(contours, c("top", "bottom", "colors"), 
            0)
        if (idx == 1) {
            cont.first = FALSE
            cont.z = plot.data[[1]]$zlim[2]
        }
        else if (idx == 2) {
        }
        else if (idx == 3) {
            cont.varycol = TRUE
            if (length(col) < 2) 
                col = rainbow(40)
        }
        else cont.col = contours
    }
    else if (is.list(contours)) {
        if (!is.null(contours$z)) 
            cz = contours$z
        if (is.numeric(cz)) 
            cont.z = cz
        else if (cz == "top") {
            cont.first = FALSE
            cont.z = plot.data[[1]]$zlim[2]
        }
        if (!is.null(contours$col)) 
            cont.col = contours$col
        if (!is.null(contours$lwd)) 
            cont.lwd = contours$lwd
        if (charmatch(cont.col, "colors", 0) == 1) {
            cont.varycol = TRUE
            if (length(col) < 2) 
                col = rainbow(40)
        }
    }
    for (i in 1:length(plot.data)) {
        dat = plot.data[[i]]
        cont.lines = NULL
        if (!missing(hook)) 
            if (!is.null(hook$pre.plot)) 
                hook$pre.plot(dat$labs)
        if (cont) 
            cont.lines = contourLines(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)
        if (cont && cont.first) {
            transf = persp(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z, zlim = dat$zlim, xlab=ylab,
                theta = theta, phi = phi, r = r, col = NA, border = NA, 
                box = FALSE)
            lapply(cont.lines, draw.cont.line)
            par(new = TRUE)
        }
        if (length(col) > 1) {
            nrz = nrow(dat$z)
            ncz = ncol(dat$z)
            zfacet = dat$z[-1, -1] + dat$z[-1, -ncz] + dat$z[-nrz, 
                -1] + dat$z[-nrz, -ncz]
            zfacet = c(zfacet/4, dat$zlim)
            facet.col = cut(zfacet, length(col))
            facet.col = col[facet.col]
        }
        transf = persp(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z, xlab = xlab, 
             zlab = zlab, zlim = dat$zlim, ylab=ylab,
            col = facet.col, border = border, box = box, theta = theta, 
            phi = phi, r = r, ticktype = ticktype)
        if (atpos == 3) 
            title(sub = dat$labs[5])
        if (cont && !cont.first) 
            lapply(cont.lines, draw.cont.line)
        if (!missing(hook)) 
            if (!is.null(hook$post.plot)) 
                hook$post.plot(dat$labs)
        plot.data[[i]]$transf = transf
    }
    invisible(plot.data)
}

persp(ct.rsm, Conc ~ kGy, col=rainbow(50), theta=60, xlab="Something",
    phi=0, r = 3, d=1, border = NULL, ltheta = -135, lphi = 0
    , shade = 0.75, zlab="CT",ylab="Concentration %", col.axis=37, font.lab=2,col.lab=33,
    contour=("colors"))
```

[image]

Comment: What about the colours in contours!

Comment: What about them? (The contours _are_ colored.)

Comment: I guess OP is looking for filled contours in the base.

Comment: I've already hacked myself through a bunch of code. I am waiting for an unambiguous problem statement.

Comment: I need the filled colors in the base, And thanks for a your effort.

Comment: I think to do filled colors you would need to replace the `draw.cont.line` function in `persp.lm` with a version that used `polygon` instead of `lines` with adjacent contours being linked  at their endpoints (which would be along the boundaries of the lower facet). You probably also need to supply extra "lines" to represent the plot boundaries.

Comment: @DWin: In `R 2.15.2`, your function produces the following error **could not find function "contour.lm"**.